# SP Page Builder mobile versions not working

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

My tablet and mobile versions of my SP Pagebuilder site are no longer working. When I inspect the page I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
>       at HTMLDocument. (55c09bec61a3ee85c3ff62e6b9fcbda7.js:47)
>       at i (55c09bec61a3ee85c3ff62e6b9fcbda7.js:5)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (55c09bec61a3ee85c3ff62e6b9fcbda7.js:5)
>       at Function.ready (55c09bec61a3ee85c3ff62e6b9fcbda7.js:5)
>       at HTMLDocument.K (55c09bec61a3ee85c3ff62e6b9fcbda7.js:5)

In house developer has no idea what it could be and neither do I.